# How can I get the contacts info on Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a backup app that cross iphone,android,phone7. Now,I want'to Read and Write contact info on phone7,but I can't find anyway to read and write in phone7 sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is not possible for a 3rd party developer.

Comment: Thank you lukas. Is there any other method, for example,I export the contacts to facebook programmly,and use phone7 import them programmly?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get them from the users Live account. (No idea how)